# Python, How to make a new class from an item in list?

Tags: python, class, nested-lists

I have a 2D list and a class as shown below. How do I make an element in the list the object name of the  class?

```
class XYZclass():
    stuff in class

xyzList = [[ someThing1, str1, str2 ],[ someThing2, str3, str4 ]]

someThing1 = XYZclass()
someThing2 = XYZclass()
```

The list is dynamic and generated externally. It can be empty or it can have many elements.
Maybe there's a better way than a list to do this

Thanks

I can't seem to find anything online.
I might be using incorrect search parameters.

Comment: Objects don't *have names*. Names (i.e. variables) can refer to an object. Don't dynamically create variables. Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: Do you want to create an object of the class inside a list?

Comment: Why not just instance the class then put the instance names into a List?

Comment: I modified the original question, hope this helps.

Comment: Names in Python are just labels assigned to objects then be used to access the object. For example if `someThing1 = "name1"` the object is the string **name1** and someThing1 is the label assigned. Then using `someThing1 = XYZclass()` reassigns the  label to that new object and the connection to the string is lost. Although there are 'hacky' ways to use string objects as name labels (see closure note Link) this is a bad idea and poor practice, There are always better ways for form code for example by putting Class instances into a List or Dict and then referring to them as List/Dict members.